# Backing Up a folder using Google Drive's API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Hey so right now I'm trying to make a discord command to upload a backup of my bot to Google Drive. So far I just have these 2 functions but I'm not sure how I could just transfer a whole folder towards a Google Drive folder.

```py
def getFileByteSize(filename):
    # Get file size in python
    from os import stat
    file_stats = stat(filename)
    print('File Size in Bytes is {}'.format(file_stats.st_size))
    return file_stats.st_size

def upload_file(drive_service, filename, mimetype, upload_filename, resumable=True, chunksize=262144):
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mimetype, resumable=resumable, chunksize=chunksize)
    # Add all the writable properties you want the file to have in the body!
    body = {"name": upload_filename} 
    request = drive_service.files().create(body=body, media_body=media).execute()
    if getFileByteSize(filename) > chunksize:
        response = None
        while response is None:
            chunk = request.next_chunk()
            if chunk:
                status, response = chunk
                if status:
                    print("Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    print("Upload Complete!")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

My file structure:
https://gyazo.com/29525bf2660888dc3ab285c8f2a7c6f5

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution?  your going to have to do a file.list to get a list of all the files in the folder and upload them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot directly upload a whole folder(s) with the nested content to Google Drive

But what you can do as a workaround is to zip your folder(s), upload the zip to Google Drive and unzip it there.